# Unable to get forEach to properly work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I completed a active/disable feature in my code that works on both Chrome/Firefox really well but for some reason I am getting an error in IE when using forEach.

Here is the error that is being displayed on IE:
[image]

On Chrome & Firefox, the div's highlight the box and the correct box shows up below.
[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

```js
"use strict";

var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.navlinksGP > a');

function enableTabButton(buttonId) {
tabButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
if (btn.id === buttonId) {
  btn.disabled = true;
  btn.style.background = '#eeaf00';
    btn.style.color = '#ffffff';
} else {
  btn.disabled = false;
  btn.style.background = '#ffffff';
    btn.style.color = '#eeaf00';
}
});
}
    enableTabButton('word');

var player = document.getElementById('player');

function wButton(element) {
  enableTabButton(element);
  if (element === "word") {
    player.innerHTML = "<h1 id=\"h1update\">Brand & Consumer Marketing</h1>";
  }
```

```html
<div class="navlinksGP">
   <a id="word" onclick="wButton(this.id); window.location='#container'" href="#">BRAND & CONSUMER MARKETING</a>
</div>
```

The only issue I have on IE is that the function enableTabButton is not working at all.

Comment: Try to use each function instade of forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged the question with keyword "jQuery" I am going to answer your question with jQuery :-)
Check the following solution if this fits your need. Works for me in IE11 as well as in all other more modern browsers.

```js
"use strict";

var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.navlinksGP > a');

function enableTabButton(buttonId) {

  $(tabButtons).each(function() {

    //console.log($(this).attr("id"));

    if ($(this).attr("id") === buttonId) {
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).css("background-color", "#eeaf00");
      $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
    } else {
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
      $(this).css("color", "#eeaf00");
    }

  });
}

enableTabButton('word');

var player = document.getElementById('player');

function wButton(element) {
  enableTabButton(element);
  if (element === "word") {
    player.innerHTML = "<h1 id=\"h1update\">Brand & Consumer Marketing</h1>";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navlinksGP">
   <a id="word" onclick="wButton(this.id); window.location='#container'" href="#">BRAND & CONSUMER MARKETING</a>
</div>
```

Comment: JonShow, this actually worked perfectly even on Windows 7 IE 11! Thanks so much! For some reason, on load the 'word' div isn't highlighted unless I click on it which then changes. Would you know a reason? the enableTabbutton('word'); is called.

Comment: Got it figured out :D

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6):

No version of Internet Explorer supports the use of `forEach()` on a NodeList, which is what's returned from `querySelectorAll()`.

There is a polyfill available to fix this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill

Comment: If that's the case, it should be a simple matter of spreading the result into an array: `[...tabButtons].forEach`

Comment: @IceMetalPunk it would be, but the spread operator doesn't work in IE either :D https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I probably hate IE more than anyone.